# Majority of engineers do not understand company standards

Tags: software-industry

I work at a mid-sized company with approximately 50 software engineers. The company is currently in the middle of creating a brand-new greenfield platform to replace its legacy platform.

At the start of the engineering effort, the technical leadership put forward a very prescribed architecture and set of design patterns. In my opinion these were good choices, which fit well with our internal tooling and the experience of the collective engineering team. These are mostly well-know industry-standard patterns and architectures and, when applied well (as in the teams I have worked on) they produce great, manageable, extensible software. These standards are well-documented internally, and as they're industry-wide there is a plethora of information on any one on the Internet.

From my observations, having access to all teams' repositories and also working with most of the teams at least once, there is widespread misuse of these patterns. Many teams seem to have devolved into a sort of 'cargo cult' programming mindset, thoughtlessly hacking together code which *nominally* adheres to the standards but goes against the 'spirit' of it. Many of these standards introduce additional complexity, but this complexity is made worthwhile by the standardisation / extensibility / flexibility that the standard provides. Most teams, by using bastardized versions of standard patterns, are encumbered with all of the complexity but none of the benefits.

I am quite fastidious about understanding and adhering to these standards, because I've seen the benefits they can bring when used correctly. However, I seem to be one of the few people in the whole engineering team like this. Personally, it is incredibly tiring to have the same conversations explaining the fundamentals of how we should be designing systems, and it's made me few friends by having to constantly critique others' work. This constant uphill battle has left me thinking that the company is composed mostly of uncaring, unthinking slobs who want to do the minimum effort to keep their jobs. As you can imagine, thinking that all day is not great for job satisfaction.

Naturally I have brought this up with the technical leadership, and while I can point out specific examples and get broad agreement that there is misuse, I don't feel I'm able to make the point that, "This is happening across all teams, by almost every engineer of every seniority, and it's ongoing". After all, I'm 1 engineer in the whole company, and I'd essentially be stating that everyone else except me isn't doing their job correctly.

When I have tried to make constructive changes with teams, 9 times out of 10 the "we have tight deadlines" card is played. However, my team also has tight deadlines but we (my voice playing no small part) hold a thin but firm line on the minimum technical standards that we'll adhere to for a given piece of work, and stakeholders tend to respect that. I can only conclude that other teams are using the "deadlines" reason as an easy excuse - if my team pushes back why can't theirs?

I'd like to understand what I, as a lone engineer, can do to constructively improve the understanding and adherence of these technical standards across the business?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't think it could come off as anything but arrogant to imply that dozens of engineers are doing their jobs incorrectly, especially as the people I would be telling this to are responsible for overseeing / managing those developers, so I would also be implying they too are partly at fault.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to get something done:

1. Ensure that the team is bought into the work to be done.
2. Enforce compliance.

In any sort of knowledge industry, we tend to favour (1) because people leave if we do (2) but sometimes (2) is a necessary evil.

Your problem here is that your technical leadership team didn't do (1) - whatever you might personally think of the architecture, it's clear the majority of the team don't care for it - and aren't doing (2). This would be a huge red flag for me as it's the classic sign of disconnected "technical leaders" who don't actually have a clue what's going on in the trenches.

> what I, as a lone engineer, can do to constructively improve the understanding and adherence of these technical standards across the business?

Almost certainly nothing. Your leadership has failed, and there's not much you can do when that's happened.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good chance that @PhilipKendall is correct and you, as a lone contributor, probably can't change the organization's culture.

You could try to improve things by taking on a sort of "methodology evangelist" role either formally or informally.  Lots of companies have a "lunch and learn" type program where once a week or once a month someone presents a topic to whoever wants to come and listen (often with the promise of the company buying lunch).  If you and your team wanted to put together presentations on "How Pattern X Solves Problem Y" where Problem Y is something that you know other teams struggle with, you could at least see who on other teams is interested in self-improvement and potentially find allies that can help push the message in other teams.  From management's perspective, it's a pretty cheap program to run-- buying an hour of training for the cost of a sandwich is a great return.

More proactive (but more difficult to pull off) would be to talk with technical leadership about establishing an architecture team that is separate from the individual technical teams whose job is to help push the standards on the team.  Usually that involves architects being assigned to work on particular projects and/ or teams and having some ability to enforce standards by signing off on design documents or code reviews or something of that nature.  Of course, that requires much greater buy-in from technical leadership on the scope of the problem.  But it also likely produces much faster results.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to portray the situation as you vs. rest of the company, with your direct team mates being at best neutral, and management being tolerant of your behavior, but not quite espousing it. If that’s correct, then no, you don’t stand a chance. You could spend days writing up/correcting design docs so that patterns are used properly, then doing code reviews to ensure the other engineers adhered to them, but realistically you won’t be able to keep up with more than 3-5 engineers.

I’ll offer two thoughts based on my personal experience:

- Some engineers see the job of writing code as a form of art, in that they will deliberately eschew established conventions, to make room for their personal flair of software development. Sometimes this results in a masterpiece, other times in a dumpster fire.
- “Our legacy platform has no future, let’s start over and do it right this time” is something I’ve witnessed, at different scales, quite a few times. As it typically happens, the new platform is designed and implemented mostly by the same people who were behind the “legacy” platform, and thus it should come as little surprise that despite optimism and goodwill, the new platform ends up being not much less of a dumpster fire than the legacy platform. Except of course the company dumped many work-months in a useless rewrite (huge opportunity cost), and in some cases the migration away from the legacy platform is never completed, resulting in the concurrent existence of the old, bad, legacy platform, and the new, differently bad, green field platform.

Answer (score 0):

> I can only conclude that other teams are using the "deadlines" reason as an easy excuse - if my team pushes back why can't theirs?

It's much more likely that they either feel like they can't push back on these deadlines or they have and it doesn't work when they try to do it.

But why should they *have* to push back? Why are the deadlines tight when they apparently don't have to be? If giving you more time in order to maintain code quality is possible, can't they just do that up front?

Since you (or your team lead or your team in general) seem to have enough respect or political capital with the stakeholders to get them to move deadlines back, you all have the best chance of having a conversation with whoever is setting deadlines and getting them to start easing up on these  time estimates in general.